# Unable to clear the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jscript

I don't know why, but the clearRect() does not work.
This is a function that is executed every time I click on a panel or every time I change the thickness' value.

```js
//When click on a menu section
$(".menuSection").click(function() {
//Show hide the selected item
$(this).next().toggle();
//hide all the other panels
$(this).next().siblings(".panel").hide();
//To update the values in the colors panel when selected
if ( $(this).prop("id") == "colors" ) {
    changeColorBySliders();
}
if ( $(this).prop("id") == "pen" ) {
     updatePreview();
}
});

//when thickness slider change:
$("#penPanel input[type=range]").on("input", updatePreview);
```

The fact is that it draws the line, but if I click it again it's doesn't reset.

```js
var $preview = $("#preview");
var contextPreview = $preview[0].getContext("2d");

//Function to update the pen's preview
function updatePreview() {
  console.log($("#thickness").val());
  var rgba = $("#mainCanvas").css("background-color");
  $("#preview").css("background-color", rgba);
  //Resetting the preview
  contextPreview.clearRect(0, 0, $preview.width, $preview.height);
  //Drawing an example path
  contextPreview.beginPath();
  contextPreview.moveTo(50, 30);
  contextPreview.lineTo(100, 110);
  contextPreview.quadraticCurveTo(115, 120, 125, 80);
  contextPreview.bezierCurveTo(145, -40, 150, 120, 200, 95);
  contextPreview.lineTo(250, 65);
  contextPreview.lineWidth = $("#thickness").val();
  contextPreview.strokeStyle = color;
  contextPreview.stroke();
  contextPreview.closePath();
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Try moving your 2 variables into the updatePreview function.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle

Comment: I can give you the git: https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/DrawingWebApp

Comment: `closePath` isn't meant to "close" `beginPath` (it isn't a syntactic close). Instead, closePath will draw a line from the current path position to the starting point of the path.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I solved the problem using this kind of declaration:

```js
var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
var contextPreview = preview.getContext("2d");
contextPreview.clearRect(0, 0, preview.width, preview.height);
```

Insted of the jquery one:

```
var $preview = $("#preview");
var contextPreview = $preview[0].getContext("2d");
```

### Why?

it's because **$preview** is a jQuery object, **$preview.width** is therefore a **function**, so when you called **clearRect()**, you were actually calling **contextPreview.clearRect(0,0, function, function)** so your rect dimensions were undefined or 0 so it wasn't clearing a single pixel.

So you can still use jQuery but be sure you call **contextPreview.clearRect(0,0, $preview[0].width, $preview[0].height)**

```js
var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
var contextPreview = preview.getContext("2d");
contextPreview.clearRect(0,0, $preview[0].width, $preview[0].height)
```

*Special Thanks to Kaiido.*

Comment: And if you want to add a why this solution does work, it's because `$preview` is a jQuery object, `$preview.width` is therefore a function, so when you called `clearRect()`, you were actually calling  `ctx.clearRect(0,0, function, function)` so your rect dimensions were `undefined` or `0` so it wasn't clearing a single pixel. So you can still use jQuery but be sure you call `ctx.clearRect(0,0, $preview[0].width,  $preview[0].height)`

Comment: You're welcome and I invite you to add it to your answer so it can help future readers too (comments are not meant to live long...)

Comment: Done and done! upvote if you thinks it's correctly done, Thank you!